# Post data to Firebase using Angular 2 without generating the automatic key,

Tags: angular, post, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Angular 2 with Firebase as a service provider. And I am not using angular-cli.

Whenever I post some data, it is posted but Firebase generates a unique key based on time stamp, which I don't need. I need to set a custom number or ID at that place. Angular 1 has the provision using child and set property. Is there any provision in Angular 2 too?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
this.af.database.object(`list/myCustomKey`).update({ age: 101 });
```

See: [https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/672](http://this.af.database.object(%60list/myCustomKey%60).update(%7B%20age:%20101%20%7D);)